# Why do C++ bit fields require me to specify a type?

Tags: c++, c++20

Why do I have to specify a type for a bit field?

```
struct MyBitField
{
    unsigned int i : 4;
}

struct MyBitField2
{
    unsigned char i : 4;
}
```

What's the difference between those two? Why do I need to specify a type at all?

Comment: To know how to interpret the bits? There isn't a unique interpretation, and the field doesn't even necessarily have to be integral either.

Comment: Because `char` will be printed as an ASCII character and `int` as a number (regardless from number of bits they occupy). Also what about `int` vs `bool` interpretation? I think the "type's **type**" is crucial as always, this is **why** you specify it.

Comment: without the type how can you know whether the field is signed or unsigned to do proper sign or zero extension? And the type also affects promotion and many other things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitfields are an "overlay" around normal members, and every member has a type. Recall that integer types in C++ are largely inherited from types in C, which were designed to map neatly to whatever primitives exist on the target architecture. This is a convenient feature to have. Bitfields sit on top of that logic; they do not replace it.

A few facts regarding this:

- [The "special width" of a bitfield does not contribute to its type](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.bit#1.sentence-4);
- the number of usable bytes of a bitfield depend on its type ([bits beyond the natural width of the type are considered padding](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.bit#1.sentence-6));
- [the semantics of an assignment to a bitfield depend (to some degree) on its type](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.bit#4.sentence-1).

**Types fundamentally underpin how objects work in C++, and how the values of those objects are to be encoded and interpreted.**

Could the bitfield feature have been designed differently? As, perhaps, a separate first-class kind of thing in the language that did not require a specific underlying type?

Perhaps, but then you'd need new rules to define bitfield integer semantics (both signed and unsigned) and conversion rules for every combination of assignment. What would be the point? We already have a type system we can use.

In your case, sure, the semantics of each object shown is the same. But other bitfields exist. You may as well ask why both `unsigned int` and `unsigned long` exist, on a system for which their respective ranges are identical: we don't design the language around very specific cases.

If all you want is a collection of untyped bits, then [`std::bitset<4>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Plus there would be the complication that machines can't allocate individual bits, so you would need even more complicated rules abut what type actually gets used. And matching hardware-defined layouts would become even more difficult.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir [Yep](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.bit#1.sentence-7).

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I guess I was thinking about the std::bitset use-case scenario only. Probably, as a general guideline, you should use std::bitset as a default and come back to bit fields only if you need the behavior of the underlying type (which then of course you need to specify). Do you think so too?

Comment: @D.R. That sounds reasonable. Of course C doesn't have `std::bitset`. Bitfields are really "a C thing", to my mind. I can't think of any persuasive use cases for them in C++ that go beyond C interop. I'm reasonably confident that if a language were designed and created today, it would not have bitfields; indeed, I can't think of any beyond C (and C++, which inherits them for interop) that ever have.